# Try to replicate jQuery parents method using Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call an onchange function on a form select element, currently working with jQuery, but want to switch to Vanilla JS. I am using the closest method on the child element to get the parent, like so;

```
var $currencyForm = $('.shopify-currency-form select').parents('form');
```

And have this JS to replicate the lack of the closest function, but keep getting console errors wherby a null value is returned when reading 'parentNode'. See below;

```
    //currencyForm is our parent selector
    const currencySelect = document.querySelector('.shopify-currency-form select');
    const currencyForm = document.querySelector('form');

    //partams are select(child) and form(parent)
    function getParentEl(el, parentSelector) {
      if (parentSelector === undefined) {
          parentSelector = document;
      }
      var parents = [];
      var p = el.parentNode;
      while (p !== parentSelector) {
          var o = p;
          parents.push(o);
          p = o.parentNode;
      }
      parents.push(parentSelector);
      return parents;
    }
    
    const formInit = getParentEl(currencySelect, currencyForm);
    //The parent node should be the last element
    const selectEl = parents[parents.length-1];
    console.log(selectEl);
```

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Answer (score 1):

You're getting `null` I think because your parent selector - `.shopify-currency-form select` - refers to an element that doesn't exist or that isn't accessible at the time you look for it. Rather than check for `undefined` here...

```
if (parentSelector === undefined) {
```

check for null...

```
if (parentSelector === null) {
```

and then this block will run, assigning another element as the value of `parentSelector` if that's what you'd like to happen.

You also need to move the initial declaration of your `parents` var out of local scope in your function in order to access it for the check you perform at the end.

Here's a fiddle with some changes and a test case for a valid class name passed in for the parent el and a made up one so you can perhaps see what's going on a bit better. Assuming a valid parent el class name is assigned and the parent el is available, this runs without any errors:

https://jsfiddle.net/abgregs/3L7mzory/2/

HTML

```
<!-- <body> -->
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first-child">
    <div class="my-target-element">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- <body> -->
```

JS

```
const currencySelect = document.querySelector('.my-target-element');

// I think that selector is giving you null, but then you're checking for undefined...
// I gave it a made up class here to replicate...
const currencyForm = document.querySelector('.made-up-selector');
 
// try uncommenting this and comment out the line above, it will work too but there will be fewer els in our parents array...
/*  const currencyForm = document.querySelector('.parent'); */

// moved out of local scope...
var parents = [];

function getParentEl(el, parentSelector) {
  // changed from checking undefined to checking null here...
  if (parentSelector === null) {
      parentSelector = document.documentElement;
  }
  // move this outside of local scope...
 /*  var parents = []; */
  console.log('parentSelector: ', parentSelector);
  var p = el.parentNode;
  while (p !== parentSelector) {
      var o = p;
      parents.push(o);
      p = o.parentNode;
  }
  
  console.log(parents.length)
  parents.push(parentSelector);
  return parents;
};

const formInit = getParentEl(currencySelect, currencyForm);
//The parent node should be the last element
const selectEl = parents[parents.length-1];
console.log(selectEl);
```